# WooCommerce: Display products in cart according to category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I need to show products in cart ordered by category. My products are assigned to a brand, and I want the products to appear in the cart area under their assigned brands.

I need listing like this:

```
Cart

    Category1

    product name    category       qty    price   Total
    aaa             category1       2      50       100 
    bbb             category1       1      10        80

    ---------------------------------------------------

    Category2   

    product name   category        qty    price     Total
    test1          category2        2      40        120
    test2          category2        1      10        100        

    -----------------------------------------------------
```

I am using this code to sort the products by taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', function() {

        global $woocommerce;
        $products_in_cart = array();
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {

            //$cart_cat = $item['wdm_user_custom_data_value'];

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($item['data']->id, 'product-cat' );
            $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $terms[0]->name;

        }

        natsort( $products_in_cart );

        $cart_contents = array();
        foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $product_title ) 
        {
            $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];
        }


        $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;

    }, 100 );
```

How to show products in cart according to category?

Comment: netsort is function to sort the array by name.This function is working it shows all products in cart according to category.But i need the cart layout i have mentioned above.i have pick up that code from here. https://gist.github.com/maxrice/6541634

Comment: can anyone suggest?